# how to concatenate values to the string 

Tags: iphone, xcode, string-concatenation

i want to cancatenate strings with comma as a separator and result must be stored in string...
comma=@",";
for(i=0;i<[resources count];i++)
    {
        Record *aRecord = [resources objectAtIndex:i];

```
    temp=aRecord.programID;
    if(i==0)
        pid=temp;
    else
    //i am using this one to cancatenate but is not working why?
```

pid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", pid,comma,temp];
    }

Comment: You are not being clear. In what form do you have the strings to be concatenated? What do you want to do with the result? Show some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-componentsJoinedByString:` method on `NSArray`:

```
NSArray *csvArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"here", @"be", @"dragons", nil];
NSLog(@"%@", [csvArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "]);
```

(from [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString:))

Comment: @lak: Yes, this will do so. It's a method on NSArray that returns an NSString. See the documentation, or try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the `id` types to `NSString` and then use the concatenation methods found in the class reference of NSString.